# Male nerd here, how on earth can I listen to an "otohime" / "sound princess"?

Tags: japan, local-customs, electronic-items

The other day, I read about ["otohime", also known as "sound princess"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilets_in_Japan#The_Sound_Princess):

> Many Japanese women are embarrassed at the thought of being heard by
>   others during urination (see paruresis). To cover the sound of
>   bodily functions, many women used to flush public toilets continuously
>   while using them, wasting a large amount of water in the process.
>   As education campaigns did not stop this practice, a device was
>   introduced in the 1980s that, after activation, produces the sound
>   of flushing water without the need for actual flushing. A Toto brand
>   name commonly found is the Otohime (音姫, lit. "Sound Princess," also
>   homophone with a legendary goddess Otohime)

As a male, is it possible to hear one in real life?

Do they exist in mixed gender / unisex toilets? If so, where are mixed gender toilets most common? (I haven't noticed any in my previous two trips)

Otherwise, should I try finding an otohime in an Akihabara shop, or possibly some sort of museum?

Comment: Could you not just flush a toilet? ;) Or see it on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ond_IaNA4wk

Comment: Sorry I don't think this is a travel question at all. But go ask it as an example question on the [**Culture of Japan** proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34330/culture-of-japan).

Comment: It's not hard - try the toilet in a hostel, or anywhere small enough that separate male and female toilets are not required.

Comment: @hippietrail In toilets that can only have one person, I thought an otohime wouldn't be required.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Again that's a cultural question. Ask somewhere likely to be populated with shy Japanese female urinators. Here's we're travellers. We know where to buy tickets and where to stay. We don't know about pee-sound-related psychology! d-: "How far away do Japanese ladies think people might hear their tinkle sounds?" - not a fricken travel question dude! d-:

Comment: Meta question: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/849/upvoting-of-off-topic-questions

Comment: Otohime? [There's an app for that](http://www.stippy.com/only-in-japan/iphone-app-virtual-toilet-flush-sound/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've used a good few of those fancy Toto do it all bidet sprayer dryer toilets, most of which (as the toilet isn't designed for a single gender) have the flush noise function. Department stores are a good bet, as are mid market restaurants.

It's really nothing to write home about though. It's the sound of a flushing toilet, which I'm sure you've heard before. Whatevs though, boats and floats and that.

Comment: I thought it will be weirder :(

Comment: @HaLaBi Me too. I'm disappointed. :P